# In App Purchase on iOS [Environment: Sandbox] keeps on appearing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have in app purchasing enabled in our application since the previous version.

Someone else worked on in-app purchasing before me and I'm continuing development of the app for the next version. However, whenever I'm trying to buy something within the app, I get an `[Environment: Sandbox]` underneath the `Are you sure you want to buy this product for x amount of money...` message.

We always get this message even if I build the app under distribution.

Will `[Environment: Sandbox]` go away once the application is accepted into the App Store? As in, will the users buy the actual product instead of somehow ending up buying the sandboxed product?

Comment: did you found out why `Environment: Sandbox]` appeared? I've got the same situation, and Apple keeps rejecting my app due to In App not working (it is working fine in Sandbox, though), so I think this can help me...

Comment: @medvedNick Environment: Sandbox appeared because I was running the application with a sandboxed account (a test user account created on itunesconnect). It seems to be normal that `Environment: Sandbox` appears when testing with a sandboxed account. To test in app purchases, create a new test user each time (on itunesconnect > manage users > test user) you make a purchase. Make sure you are logged out of any other Apple accounts (go to Settings on the iPhone for this).

Comment: can you clarify please why do we need to create new test user every time?

Comment: @medvedNick That's the way we test in-app purchases in our application. I think we were getting errors when we tried to reuse the same account. I might be wrong though, I haven't tried testing this for a while. Related to your problem, are your in-app purchases set available to be purchased in the US as well? Or are they geographically limited?

Comment: no geographical limits... I will try to create new test users, may help me. Can you give a quick look onto my question please, if you have a little time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398710/in-app-purchase-not-working-while-reviewing-by-apple ? thank you

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK once the product(which you want to sell as part of IAP) on the iTunes store is approved, the message of sandbox will be removed. This will be done when you put your application for approval process. User will automatically diverted for actual product and not the sand box one.

Comment: What's weird is that the product we are testing against is already validated as an IAP (previous app version). The app is build in Distribution, we are using real accounts (App Store, our application). The only reason I could imagine it is still showing the sandbox message is that our app is not validated by the App Store...does that make sense? Am I worrying for nothing?

Comment: Are you testing it on simulator or on device?