# In App Purchase not working while reviewing by Apple

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I have an app with working In App purchases, it was approved by Apple and it is now in Appstore. A few days ago I submitted a new version of the app with one new consumable purchase, implemented as others were.

I'm using MKStoreKit and this method to buy a feature:

```
// ... showing loading window
[[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:feature
                                onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature,NSData* purchasedReceipt, NSArray* availableDownloads) {
     // ... some handler and close loading
                               onCancelled:^ {
              // ... another handler and close loading
                                        }];
```

In Sandbox mode this method ends either in onComplete block, either onCancelled block, getting all correct identifiers (with new purchase too). However, due to Apple's reviewer's answer my loading is never closed. Also, they say that new purchase is now in Developer Action Needed Status, but can not edit it now, and I can not delete it (even if I check Cleared For Sale for NO).

May the problem be in the new purchase product or is it something else? I'm totally confused...

What can I do? Anyone encountered such a problem? I can not reproduce the error in Sandbox since it is working fine, so is there any way I can get the same result as in the Apple Review Team?

Comment: If the new IAP has a status of `Developer Action Needed` then you need to address that before you resubmit your app for review.

Comment: @neilco may that cause other identifiers not to load from iTunes? Can I request deleting that In App by Apple (as I've said, I can do nothing with it...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that was a strange bug on Apple servers caused by this new In App. I don't know why, but I could not delete it. Also, it had broken all In Apps but only while Apple Review testing, as I've said, all was fine in Sandbox mode. The solution was to write to Apple's support, and after a while they fixed it, I deleted this In App and everything started to work as is should.